# Login with Facebook with Dialog in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

How to implement this login with facebook?
I've followed this tutorial https://www.androidlearning.in/facebook-login-for-android-app/ but it throws a complete activity (the traditional way).

I have facebook application installed

In applications like Memrise, Bandlab, etc. Shows me that Dialog but no in my application

Also I try with

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList([...]);
```

but dont works...

I want:

[image: Imagen]

My app Show me:

[image: Imagen]

Comment: what was your issue ?pls clear that.

Comment: @RickyPatel Edit my question with a new image

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog
try with this.

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: @PratikKate No... I continue with the old authentication :/

Comment: Well, I'm also looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem as you 30 minutes ago, but I was using a custom button for Facebook and the following code inside onCreate for calling Facebook Login:

```
loginButton = (CircularProgressButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
            }
        });

        //Register a callback
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
                                        try {
                                            nome = object.getString("name");
                                            email = object.getString("email");
                                            String idfb  = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
                                            logarFb(idfb, nome, email);

                                        } catch(JSONException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        //cancelled
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                     //error
                    }
                });
```

I changed it to Facebook Login button:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_fb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Now that's how my code looks like now, much cleaner:

```
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_fb);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                getUserDetails(loginResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                funcoes.aviso(MainActivity.this,"Você cancelou o login",R.color.red500,3000, R.drawable.ic_triste);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                funcoes.dialogoMsg(MainActivity.this,"Há algo de errado com o login do Facebook :/");
            }
        });
}

 protected void getUserDetails(final LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted( JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            nome = object.getString("name");
                            email = object.getString("email");
                            String idfb  = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
                            logarFb(idfb, nome, email);

                        } catch(JSONException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
        data_request.setParameters(parameters);
        data_request.executeAsync();

    }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

If do you have Facebook App installed, that's should be enough to have the Facebook Login as Dialog Box instead of an FullScreen Activity.

If you want so, follow this guide If you forgot some other setting: https://www.studytutorial.in/android-facebook-integration-and-login-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The dialog will appear only if you have the facebook app installed on your phone , other wise you will get a web view.   Try installing the app and then logging in.

Comment: I have facebook application installed

In applications like Memrise, Bandlab, etc. Shows me that Dialog but no in my application

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the permission "user_birthday" If you defined in your permissions.

`LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(context,Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));`

As some permissions needs for "App Review"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not related to the question

Comment: Recently I'm facing this issue so what I did is removed my permission which needs App Review,  I have three permissions email,public_profile and user_birthday, after removing user_birthday permission it's showing me the dialog. & one more thing I did was to update the facebook application.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my permission set

Existing code

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, listOf("user_photos", "email", "public_profile"))
```

Working code

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, listOf("email"))
```